# Keep Azure AD B2C Login Popup Window Visible

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

My company is trying to implement an Azure AD B2C login with popups from within our Angular site, and we are using msal v0.2.2 2018-08-17 to do so. We invoke the login pop-up by calling msal.js's loginPopup method.

The popup seems to display correctly, but we've noticed that if the main window subsequently receives focus, the login popup gets hidden behind the main window. While it may not be correct to force the pop-up to remain on the top all the time, I would expect that the pop-up would at least come to the top when the user re-clicks the same login link, yet it doesn't. The user is left clicking the login link to no effect. It acts as a dead link, and the pop-up remains under the main window.

I have looked into getting a handle to the pop-up window(s) that msal.js creates so that I can manipulate it/them myself, but there is no handle to the popup returned to the caller that I can see.

How might this issue be remedied?